# Show gray image on hover over div, color image on hover over gray image

Tags: css

I want do something like this:
Show text in div, on hover show gray image next to text
and on hover over gray image show color image.

here's what i done sofar:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='line'>text text 1<a href='#1'><div class='image'>
</div></a></div>

<div class='line'>text text 2<a href='#2'><div class='image'>
</div></a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image                  { visibility:hidden; height:48px;width:48px;background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZP-OED3SNXR6bzDbYbAxQUUBIobAu60g1Ft9Wapv_ysUd37ANcw);}
.line :hover .image       {visibility:visible;}     
.line .image:hover image        {background-image:     url(http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStjRtP8jtJNFLgnzWT-plN-JGLLb0L4ZSD4wqKksAs517dvj_rSA);}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UT56U/1/

Is it possible without jQuery or JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible, but you have to use the right selectors.

```
.line :hover .image
```

The space between `.line` and `:hover` here would mean a *descendant* element of `.line` being hovered – so remove the space, to have it react on hover of `.line` itself.

```
.line .image:hover image
```

You have no `.image` element here that is itself a descendant of an `.image`, so this selector does not apply as well. Make that `.line .image:hover` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/UT56U/2/